# No overload for method 'Deserialize' takes 2 arguments?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, asp.net-web-api, serialization

I am trying to call a web api with GET method which returns json. My code is working fine and returning me json data. but the challenge i am facing in deserializing the data. My code is: (.Net framework 3.5)

```
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("url");
req.Method = "GET";
req.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();

Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader re = new StreamReader(stream);
String json = re.ReadToEnd();
```

Above code is working fine and returning data. The problem is in below line:

```
wrapper w = (wrapper)new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(json, typeof(wrapper));
```

It shows the error:

**No overload for method 'Deserialize' takes 2 arguments.**

What should I do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: if i remove the second argument from deserialize method, it still shows error that:  The type arguments for method 'System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize<T>(string)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

`JavaScriptSearializer` available in .Net Framework since version 3.5, but in version 3.5 there is no overload of `Deserialize` method which takes 2 arguments. Overload with 2 arguments is available since version 4.0. There is only one `Deserialize` method for 3.5 which you need to use by passing generic type instead of second argument.

```
wrapper w = (wrapper)new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<wrapper>(json);
```

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee191864(v=vs.110).aspx) is the documentation about the method you want to use. If you scroll to the bottom of the page there is *Version Information* section, in which you can find that this method is available since version 4.0

Comment: instead of wrapper in Deserialize<wrapper>, should i write the classname of wrapper class, because this gives me null records. and if i write classname instead of wrapper it shows the error that:Cannot convert type 'with3._5GetMethod.Form1.SalesPerson' to 'with3._5GetMethod.Form1.wrapper' ??

Comment: there should be class name of wrapper class

Comment: can you add wrapper class and json snippets to the question

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Newtonsoft.Json lib?

`using Newtonsoft.Json;`

you can do it like this

```
wrapper w = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<wrapper>(json);
```